# how can I add new query to gridview?

Tags: c#

I have a list of data and I want to use that data to search in a table.The query works fine but it doesn't keep previously data.Is there any solution for it?

here's the code:

```
foreach (string Id in LstID)
{
    GdEmp.DataSource = employee.ShowData(Id);
    GdEmp.DataBind();

}
```

here's the query:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string family { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    ....


public List<Employee> ShowData(string Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var Query = from P in Bank.employee
                where P.Id == Id
                select new Employee
                {
                    family = P.Family,
                    name= P.Name,
                    ...
                };
            return Query.ToList();

        }
     }
```

Comment: You are overwriting the datasource for GdEmp on every iteration of the foreach loop. This will only keep the data from the last iteration. Try to give us a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish and we might be able to help you.

Comment: That code will only show the data for the last `id` in the list.

Comment: I know,but I want to keep previously data.how can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't keep previous data? what is previous data in the code you posted? more info needed?

Comment: I always get the last query.but I want to keep all queris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function that takes in the list of Id's you want to show and returns a list with the corresponding information, instead of getting them one by one.

```
GdEmp.DataSource = employee.ShowAllData(LstID);
GdEmp.DataBind();
```

Use this function:

```
public List<Employee> ShowAllData(List<string> LstID)
{
        var q = from P in Bank.employee
                where LstID.Contains(P.Id)
                select new Employee
                {
                       family = P.Family,
                       name   = P.Name,
                       ...
               };
        return q.ToList();
}
```